# プロトコルを条件で使うには

Tags: swift, swift3

プロトコルについて勉強をしていますが、何かもう一つ理解ができません。
下記は、数値の範囲をコードポイントと見立てて、指定されたコードポイントを文字に表示する
関数をジェネリックにしたいと思っています。
指定された数値を、Int型にして、コードポイントに変換して表示しようと思っていますが、
条件の立て方が分かりません。下記のコードでは、T型をIntegerプロトコル適合したところで、Intのイニシャライザでは、どの型になるのか（またはIntegerプロトコルから作成した型を独自に作成した場合もある）が分からないので、コンパイルが通らないことは理解できました。
が、問題が解決できません。UInt8,UInt16,UInt32,Int型に対応したいと思っています。

```
func codePointToMoji<T:Integer>(_ range:CountableClosedRange<T>)->Void{

    for c in range
    {
         let codePoint = Int(c)
         let d = UnicodeScalar(codePoint) 
         if let s = d{
            print(s)
         }
    }
}


var a = (0 as UInt8)...71
var b = (48165 as UInt16)...48170
var c = 0x0300...0x036F



codePointToMoji(a)
codePointToMoji(b)
codePointToMoji(c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このように変更を加えると、エラーなしで実行できるようになりました。

```
func codePointToMoji<T:Integer>(_ range:CountableClosedRange<T>)->Void{

    for c in range
    {
        let codePoint = Int(c.toIntMax()) // 変更
        let d = UnicodeScalar(codePoint)
        if let s = d{
            print(s)
        }
    }
}


var a = (0 as UInt8)...71
var b = (48165 as UInt16)...48170
var c = 0x0300...0x036F



codePointToMoji(a)
codePointToMoji(b)
codePointToMoji(c)
```

`toIntMax()`は、`Integer`プロトコルがInheritしている`_Integer`プロトコルがInheritしている`IntegerArithmetic`プロトコルが実装しています。`IntMax`型の整数値を返し、`IntMax`型は、`Int64`のTypeAliasです。そのままでは`UnicodeScalar`のイニシアライザに渡せないので、`Int()`で変換しています。この`toIntMax()`メソッドは、重要なキーワードのような気がしています。

Comment: `IntMax`は(少なくとも現在のSwiftでは)64ビットか32ビットかに関わらず`Int64`のtypealiasで、`Int`のtypealiasではありません。64bit環境でも`Int`と`Int64`は別のデータ型、32bit環境でも`Int`と`Int32`は別のデータ型です。従って`Int64`型の値である`toIntMax()`メソッドの結果を`Int`型に変換する場合には、(32bitであろうと64bitであろうと)イニシャライザを使う必要があります。

Comment: @OOPer ご指摘ありがとうございます。まちがって覚えてました。`IntMax`という名称から、実行環境で、サイズが変化するものと思い込んでしまいました（おかげで`Int()`で変換しなければいけない理由もわかりました）。回答本文を、修正します。